# How to vectorize a matlab script converting a 3d matrix to a single vector?

Tags: matlab, loops, nested, vectorization

I am writing a graphical representation of numerical stability of differential operators and I am having trouble removing a nested for loop. The code loops through all entries in the X,Y, plane and calculates the stability value for each point. This is done by finding the roots of a polynomial of a size dependent on an input variable (length of input vector results in a polynomial 3d matrix of size(m,n,(lenght of input vector)). The main nested for loop is as follows.

```
for m = 1:length(z2)
   for n = 1:length(z1)
        pointpoly(1,:) = p(m,n,:);
        r = roots(pointpoly);
        if isempty(r),r=1e10;end
        z(m,n) = max(abs(r));
    end
end
```

The full code of an example numerical method (Trapezoidal Rule) is as follows.  Any and all help is appreciated.

```
alpha = [-1 1];
beta = [.5 .5];
Wind = 2;
Wsize = 500;
if numel(Wind) == 1
    Wind(4) = Wind(1);
    Wind(3) = -Wind(1);
    Wind(2) = Wind(4);
    Wind(1) = Wind(3);
end
if numel(Wsize) == 1
    Wsize(2) = Wsize;
end
z1 = linspace(Wind(1),Wind(2),Wsize(1));
z2 = linspace(Wind(3),Wind(4),Wsize(2));
[Z1,Z2] = meshgrid(z1,z2);
z = Z1+1i*Z2;
p = zeros(Wsize(2),Wsize(1),length(alpha));
for n = length(alpha):-1:1
    p(:,:,(length(alpha)-n+1)) = alpha(n)-z*beta(n);
end
for m = 1:length(z2)
    for n = 1:length(z1)
        pointpoly(1,:) = p(m,n,:);
        r = roots(pointpoly);
        if isempty(r),r=1e10;end
        z(m,n) = max(abs(r));
    end
end
figure()
surf(Z1,Z2,z,'EdgeColor','None');
caxis([0 2])
cmap = jet(255);
cmap((127:129),:) = 0;
colormap(cmap)
view(2);
title(['Alpha Values (',num2str(alpha),') Beta Values (',num2str(beta),')'])
```

EDIT::
I was able to remove one of the for loops using the reshape command. So;

```
for m = 1:length(z2)
   for n = 1:length(z1)
        pointpoly(1,:) = p(m,n,:);
        r = roots(pointpoly);
        if isempty(r),r=1e10;end
        z(m,n) = max(abs(r));
    end
end
```

has now become

```
gg = reshape(p,[numel(p)/length(alpha) length(alpha)]);
r = zeros(numel(p)/length(alpha),1);
for n = 1:numel(p)/length(alpha)
    temp = roots(gg(n,:));
    if isempty(temp),temp = 0;end
    r(n,1) = max(abs(temp));
end

z = reshape(r,[Wsize(2),Wsize(1)]);
```

This might be one for loop, but I am still going through the same number of elements. Is there a way to use the roots command on all of my rows at the same time?

Comment: Hmm. The `roots` function takes only one input, which must be a vector, so the answer to your question "is there a way to use the roots command on all of my rows at the same time?" is "no". But maybe there is another solution - for example, what do you know about the dimension of the polynomials (or `size(p,3)` in your notation)? Can `alpha` be arbitrarily long or will it always have length 2 or 3?

Comment: the sizes of alpha and beta will always be know because they are the inputs to this function (alpha relates to the number of solutions to the diff eq you use and beta relates the number of past derivatives).  Some examples include the above trapezoidal rule, (alpha = [-1 1] beta = [0 1] is backward euler or alpha = [-1 0 1], beta = [1/3 4/3 1/3] for Simpson’s Method. But in General alpha and beta can be any size vector to represent any n step solver. The only requirement is that alpha and beta are the same length.